Prove that $|F|=K(K-1)^{n-1}$ , where $F :[ f:(1,2,....,n)\rightarrow (1,2,....,k);(n\ge 3,k\ge2),f(i)\ne f(i+1),\forall i,1\le i\le n-1]$
For a finite set $A$, let $|A|$ denote the number of elements in the set $A$.
Let  $F$ be the set of all functions  $$f:[1,2,...,n]\rightarrow [1,2,...,k] (n\ge 3,k\ge 2)$$
Satisfying,$$f(i)\ne f(i+1),\forall i,1\le i\le n-1$$
Show that $|F|=k(k-1)^{n-1}$.
MY APPROACH
If $n=k$ ,then we are left with $f$ as one-one function, now in order to calculate possible arrangements of different mapping of elements of $f$ satisfying the criteria of $f(i)\ne f(i+1)$, i tried to calculate the casses for negation of the statement, but ended up in getting no case as the last digit $n$ would be mapped with $n+1$, which in turn does not belong to range according to my assumption, but that dosent mean, there does not exist any function like that, and now i am stuck with no clue on how to calculate further, please help!!!

The question is really simple and can be understood in this way:

We need to find the umber of possible functions $f:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to \{1,2,\dots,k\}$: such that $f(i)=f(i+1)$.

Now,
For $f(1)$ there are $k$ different values which it can take. thus giving $'k'$ ways for $f(1)$.
For $f(2)\ne f(1)$ there are $(k-1)$ different possible values which it can take.
Similarly for $f(3)\ne f(2)$ [$f(3)$ may or may not be equal to $f(1)$] so we again have $(k-1)$ different possible values which $f(3)$ can take
$\vdots$
For $f(n)$ we again have $(k-1)$ different possible values.
so the total number of functions $f$ which can be formed are:
$K\cdot\underbrace{(k-1)\cdot (k-1)\cdots (k-1)}_{(n-1)\text{ times}}$
$= k(k-1)^{n-1}$
So,
$\vert F\vert=k(k-1)^{n-1}$

it wad quite simple though, yet i was not able to notice this simple counting,thanks for helping me out.
